# Как ограничить права пользователя?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu

Пользователю дается доступ к системе через ssh на VPS:

```
adduser someone
```

Нужно ограничить доступ так, чтобы пользователь мог посещать только свою папку и еще папку /sites/someone. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, так выставьте права доступа соответствующие. Увы, ACL в линуксе сделан не очень удобно. Если работать по классической схеме с правами в виде набора флагов rwxrwxrwx в порядке owner-group-others, то придется добавлять группу, которая имеет доступ ко всем каталогам, в эту группу добавлять всех пользователей, кроме `someone`, а затем просто урезать для всех каталогов права others, чтобы `someone` не мог получить туда доступ. Хотя это решение ни эффективным, ни элегантным не назвать. Хочу отметить, что в обычной инсталляции Линукса права для каталогов, отличных от домашних, выставлены достаточно разумно, чтобы произвольный пользователь не имел туда доступа на запись. На исполнение и чтение права есть, но обычно это роли не играет.Если же используется SELinux или AppArmor, то там система прав более гибкая.

Answer (score 1):

Возможный вариант решения - это изменение домашней папки с помощью chroot. Из [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot):

> Программа, запущенная с изменённым корневым каталогом, будет иметь доступ только к файлам, содержащимся в данном каталоге. Поэтому, если нужно обеспечить программе доступ к другим каталогам или файловым системам (например, /proc), нужно заранее примонтировать в целевом каталоге необходимые каталоги или устройства.

Пример: [Chroot в домашнюю папку](http://blog.antage.name/posts/sftp-chroot-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8E%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83.html).